# Is it good to return a "static char[]" string in C?

Tags: c, string

I have a group of functions all building a logging string like this:

```
...
// Top level snprintf call
snprintf(buffer, BUFSIZ, "%s %s %s", dump_1(obj), dump_2(obj), dump_3(obj));
...

static char *dump_1(my_own_type_t obj)
{
        static char t1[BUFSIZ];
        // Logic printing obj data into t1
        return t1;
}

static char *dump_2(my_own_type_t obj)
{
        static char t2[BUFSIZ];
        // Logic printing obj data into t2
        return t2;
}

static char *dump_3(my_own_type_t obj)
{
        static char t3[BUFSIZ];
        // Logic printing obj data into t3
        return t3;
}
```

Is this a good way of doing it, or is there a better way of achieving the same thing? I could use dynamically allocated strings instead, but then I would have to add memory management which would make the code more complicated. I could also pass buffer around and then write straight into the buffer, but that would mean a lot of additional snprintf calls as I would have to call snprintf every time I want to add something to the string.

EDIT:
In my case thread safety is not an issue, and the logging calls are not re-entrant. So theoretically I would be fine with keeping things the way they are. However, it feels cleaner somehow to do it as per mcleod_ideafix's suggestion. That way I wouldn't need any static variables, and I would still keep snprintf calls to a minimum. The only downside is declaring a lot of local buffers, but I feel that is manageable in my case. Thanks much for all the feedback.

Comment: Does it matter to your situation that this is completely not thread safe?

Comment: This fails badly if you ever run multiple threads, or even just make reentrant calls.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: Nope thread safety is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could also pass buffer around and then write straight into the
>   buffer, but that would mean a lot of additional snprintf calls as I
>   would have to call snprintf every time I want to add something to the
>   string.

Not necesarily:

```
...
char s1[BUFSIZ],s2[BUFSIZ],s3[BUFSIZ];
...
// Top level snprintf call
snprintf(buffer, BUFSIZ, "%s %s %s", dump_1(obj,s1), dump_2(obj,s2), dump_3(obj,s3));
...
//or like this:
...
dump_1(obj,s1);
dump_2(obj,s2);
dump_3(obj,s3);
snprintf(buffer, BUFSIZ, "%s %s %s", s1, s2, s3);
...

char *dump_1(my_own_type_t obj, char *s)
{
        // Logic printing obj data into s
        return s;
}

char *dump_2(my_own_type_t obj, char *s)
{
        // Logic printing obj data into s
        return s;
}

char *dump_3(my_own_type_t obj, char *s)
{
        // Logic printing obj data into s
        return s;
}
```

The second way also allows you to clearly stablish the execution order of the different `dump_X()` functions, something that may not be clear if they are called within the `snprintf()` parameter evaluation (in fact, the first way will possibly call `dump_3()` first, then `dump_2()` and then `dump_1()` because of the way `C_decl` functions pushes its arguments on the stack: from right to left. You may or may not care about it)

Comment: Actually that is a very good point, I overlooked that option. Thanks much!

Answer (score 6):

Returning a pointer to a static is fine as long as you realize that it makes the function non-reentrant. So, for example,

```
snprintf(buffer, BUFSIZ, "%s %s", dump_1(obj1), dump_1(obj2));
```

will fail, because the two calls to dump_1() will interfere, and may not be called in the order you expect. Also, you won't be able to use the functions in threaded code. Best practice for general-purpose string functions is to pass the output string and size as an argument, just like snprintf does.

Comment: The two calls to dump_1 will interfere, or they just may interfere?

Comment: @EricZ In this example it *will* interfere because `dump_1` always returns the same pointer (and both of the `dump_1` function calls run and complete with side-effects - in any order - before snprintf is entered).

Comment: @user2864740, Oh yes! It's my fault to ignore the same call to `dump_1`. Thanks for that. +1

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfectly valid way to return a string.

It's not the right approach in every case, however. For one thing, if your function is called from multiple threads, they'll all be using the same buffer and will overwrite each other.

Comment: Not just multiple threads: all re-entrancy (and then some) is lost.

Comment: Sure, but that is essentially controlled from within the function, and not how it is called.

Comment: Hence my addition of "then some". It's not strictly related to reentrancy, but whatever this situation is called: `char *a = dump_1(A); char *b = dump_1(B);`, might be surprising.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good way to return pointer to static array local to a function. making a variable static is just fixing it's value for the next call of the function.

If you declare a pointer to char an assigne to it the value returned by the function then define a new pointer and assigne to it the value returned by the same function. this will make the two pointers points to the same address and changing the value stored in the adress pointed to by one of the pointers make it changed for the other pointer as they are pointing to the same address, as this exemple explain:

```
int i = 1;

static char *f()
{
    static char a[10];
    if (i){
        strcpy(a, "value 1");
        i = 0;
    }
    else {
        strcpy(a, "value 2");
    }
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    char *x1 = f();
    char *x2 = f();

    printf("%s\n", x1);
    printf("%s\n", x2);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
value 2
value 2
```

Instead the best way to do it is to declare a pointer inside the function and allocate memory for the content